# CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification to new CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification will lead to crash as follow

Tags: ios, exc-bad-access

1. if comment out the code "dispatch_async" it will lead to crash at [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc]init] as EXC_BAD_ACCESS;
2. if i don't judge "if (!networkInfo)" instead of code "CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc]init];" will lead to memory up fast!Thanks!

   ```
   viewdidload: [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(updateAppCellWithNetworkType:) name:CTRadioAccessTechnologyDidChangeNotification object:nil];

   - (void)updateAppCellWithNetworkType:(id)sender{

   **//dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{**

   NSString *type = nil;
   Reachability *currentReach = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostName:@"www.apple.com"];
   if (currentReach.isReachableViaWiFi) {
   type =  @"WiFi";
   }else{

   static CTTelephonyNetworkInfo *networkInfo = nil;

   **if (!networkInfo) {
       networkInfo = [[CTTelephonyNetworkInfo alloc]init];
   }**

   type =  [self getTelephonyNetworkTypeWithCTRadioAccessTechnology:networkInfo.currentRadioAccessTechnology];
   }
   }
   ```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is advised that not to create CTTelephonyNetworkInfo object from the Notification observer method. Check the documentation given in the [objc.io](https://www.objc.io/issues/5-ios7/iOS7-hidden-gems-and-workarounds/) link under "Know Your Radio" section.

This might help, I had similar experience and doing this fixed the crash.